# Multiple Inner Join from tables with millions of rows

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database with multiple tables "InnoDB" with millions of row in it. Let say, The majority of interactions with tables are simple select/insert statements. But i have to make some Inner joints for statistics purpose.

I have two servers with Master/Slave replication. Master is for write only and slave for read to separate the queries manually without using a loadbalancer like ProxySQL ... And it works fine for the simple queries.

Servers specs :

```
CPU : Intel Xeon E5-1630v3 - 4c/8t - 3.7 GHz/3.8 GHz 
RAM : 64 GB ECC 2133 MHz
Latency between the two servers is 1ms (measured)
```

The problem is when i run the statistic module, i got like 99% of CPU usages and queries take a lot of time. Ex : 1 INNER JOIN take 2 or 3 sec (With indexes) but when i launch a lot of them, it can take up to 90 sec.

Its clear to me that i have to add more servers and build an architecture around with a load balancer. but before i dive to this, can anyone suggest me a working solution for my situation please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. MASTER & SLAVE data
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your reply @lemonina

I wonder why my question has a -1 ...

I run a Benchmark before a reinstall all with sysbench :

```
sysbench /usr/share/sysbench/oltp_read_write.lua --mysql-host=localhost --mysql-port=3306 --mysql-user=sysbench --mysql-password='sysbench' --mysql-db=sysbench --db-driver=mysql --tables=6 --table-size=30000000 prepare
```

```
sysbench --db-driver=mysql --mysql-user=sysbench --mysql_password=sysbench --mysql-db=sysbench --mysql-host=127.0.0.1 --mysql-port=3306 --tables=6 --table-size=30000000 --threads=16 --time=300 --events=0 --report-interval=1 /usr/share/sysbench/oltp_read_write.lua run
```

here is the result :

```
SQL statistics:
    queries performed:
        read:                            1039458
        write:                           296988
        other:                           148494
        total:                           1484940
    transactions:                        74247  (247.46 per sec.)
    queries:                             1484940 (4949.13 per sec.)
    ignored errors:                      0      (0.00 per sec.)
    reconnects:                          0      (0.00 per sec.)

General statistics:
    total time:                          300.0391s
    total number of events:              74247

Latency (ms):
         min:                                    5.08
         avg:                                   64.65
         max:                                  805.41
         95th percentile:                      170.48
         sum:                              4800305.37

Threads fairness:
    events (avg/stddev):           4640.4375/18.04
    execution time (avg/stddev):   300.0191/0.00
```

There was no specific configuration with this test.

So made some changes based on what you suggest :

- innodb_buffer_pool_size = 48G | Suggest between 60 and 80 % of RAM based on [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/91354/264237)
- innodb_log_file_size = 10G  | From [Percona](https://www.percona.com/blog/what-is-a-big-innodb_log_file_size/)
- innodb_thread_concurrency = 0 | From [Link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/81210/264237)
- innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1 | From [Link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12612/264237)
- sync_binlog=1 | From [Link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12612/264237)
- innodb_file_per_table (NO) | From [Link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/111681/264237)
- For the caching, i don't think it will work because there is new data every second
- SET GLOBAL innodb_redo_log_capacity = 8589934592; for Replica
- Scaling horizontally with ProxySQL will be a great idea. I already tested this, but I dropped down this solution because the dispatching of the queries was slow. I found after a solution for this, so i think i will test this in a near future.
- I also read about dividing the database between servers, I didn’t test it, but i have to figure out which tables i can put in the same server for my INNER JOINTs.

Here is my new configuration :

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 48G
innodb_log_file_size = 10G
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
sync_binlog=1

max_connections = 10000
wait_timeout = 300
interactive_timeout = 10
connect_timeout = 60
binlog_expire_logs_seconds = 86400

server-id = 1
log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
max_binlog_size = 1G
slow_query_log = 1
```

And the result from the same test :

```
SQL statistics:
    queries performed:
        read:                            7376012
        write:                           2107432
        other:                           1053716
        total:                           10537160
    transactions:                        526858 (1756.07 per sec.)
    queries:                             10537160 (35121.32 per sec.)
    ignored errors:                      0      (0.00 per sec.)
    reconnects:                          0      (0.00 per sec.)

General statistics:
    total time:                          300.0205s
    total number of events:              526858

Latency (ms):
         min:                                    2.76
         avg:                                    9.11
         max:                                  116.71
         95th percentile:                       14.46
         sum:                              4799015.34

Threads fairness:
    events (avg/stddev):           32928.6250/51.95
    execution time (avg/stddev):   299.9385/0.00
```

I'm not sure if the reinstall of the 100 Go database can impact the performance obtained or the configuration did.

What do you think ?

Comment: I am glad it worked, here are a few more suggestions: **optimize your SQL queries**(breaking down the complex queries into smaller and avoid using wildcards) -- **query caching**(stores results from frequently called selects) --  **connection pooling**(reusable connections instead of a new one)

Answer (score 2):

here are some suggestions to improve your performance:

- check query execution plan -- identify any potential bottlenecks in the query
- make sure that you have appropriate indexes for the columns used in `JOIN`
- optimize database configuration -- check your config file `(my.cnf)` and adjust it for the hardware configuration and workload (parameters such as "innodb_buffer_pool_size", "innodb_log_file_size", "innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit", "innodb_thread_concurrency", etc)
- use caching -- caching layer using tools like Redis or Memcached to cache frequently accessed data and reduce the load on the DB
- partitioning -- consider partitioning large tables with millions of rows based on date|geographic location
- optimize the schema -- normalize the tables to reduce redundancy + use appropriate data types for your columns
- upgrade your hardware -- higher number of CPU cores - faster disk I/O - more RAM

as you have already identified, scaling horizontally with a load balancer may be the best long-term solution to handle increasing loads